# no soundcards found

Tags: fedora, audio, alsa, alsamixer

```
sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
```

yields this error:

> aplay: main:831: audio open error: Host is down

Without sudo there is no error and a delay as if playing the sound, but the speakers don't output any sound.

```
$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

lspci does detect the soundcards however:

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)

and

> 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6790/6850/6870 / 7720 OEM]

also

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7f00000 irq 36
1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                     HDA ATI HDMI at 0xf7e40000 irq 37
```

I've already tried `modprobe snd-hda-intel`, but it had no effect.

In alsamixer there is a single *Master* channel, not muted, full volume.

Running on fedora server 37.

How can I make sound work?

Comment: You probably have a sound server (PulseAudio, Pipewire or something) that is keeping the physical audio device busy. If you have (or can install) `pavucontrol`, run it (it is a GUI program) and check that the selections on the `Configuration` tab make sense, then  make sure the output device you actually want has the checkmark on the `Output Devices` tab.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no X server on that machine and am limited to command line tools.